# Copying a UIImageView subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview, nscopying

I have several objects in an array. These objects are from a `UIImageView` subclass.

These objects' class has several `@synthesize`d properties.

At some point I have to create a duplicate of an object in a given position on the array at a different coordinate. Then I do:

```
id objectToDuplicate = [myArray objectAtIndex:x];
id newObject = [objectToDuplicate copy];
CGPoint newCenter = [objectToDuplicate center];
newCenter.x = newCenter.x + 10;
newCenter.y = newCenter.y + 10;
[newObject setCenter:newCenter];
[self.view addSubview:newObject];
[newObject release];
```

When this code runs, nothing happens. I mean, no object is created with a 10 pixel offset and I see this message in the console:

> ** ... copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ... **

The objects have several elements such as text boxes, labels, and images that have shadow, glow, etc., and the new object has to have the same values for text colors, shadows, glows, size, images, etc., as the original.

I thought `UIImageView` had the `NSCopying` protocol in place. If this is the problem, how do I implement that?

Please refrain from sending me to the docs, I have read them and this is why I am asking here. Please give me practical examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read that `UIImageView` implements `NSCopying`? It doesn't, you have to do that yourself for your subclass.

Comment: I can't resist: [UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).